# numpy remove every row with standart deviation of 0

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to remove every row in a numpy array that has a std of 0. I've written the code below but it just doesn't do what I

```
for i in array:
    if i.std() == 0:
       array = np.delete(array i, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could creat a new numpy array to complete it.

```
std = np.std(array,axis=1)
index = np.where(std!=0)[0]
new_array = array[index]
```